# Why my site Reload When I execute some function using redux-persist?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist, redux-promise-middleware

Hey I ran into Problem I am using Redux Persist to persist Data in redux State But When i Click on Some Function like Save button or on Change it Reload the Page or redirect to HomePage I dont know why before using persist it was Fine
here is my code For Reduc Setup

```
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

const rootReducers = combineReducers({
  loggedIn: userReducer,
  category: CategoryReducer,
  subcategory: SubCategoryReducer,
  product: ProductReducer,
  search: SearchReducer,
  cart: AddtoCart,
  drawer: drawer,
  siteSetting:SiteReducer
});
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducers);

export default persistedReducer;
```

Below is my Main index.js file

```
import { configureStore,createAction} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {Provider} from "react-redux"
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension"
import persistedReducer from './reducers'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { persistStore,FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER, } from 'redux-persist'
const store=configureStore({reducer:persistedReducer,middleware:((getDefaultMiddleware)=>
getDefaultMiddleware({
  serializableCheck:{
    ignoreActions:[FLUSH,
      REHYDRATE,
      PAUSE,
      PERSIST,
      PURGE,
      REGISTER,]
  }
})
)},composeWithDevTools());
const persistor = persistStore(store);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(

  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}  >
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Can any one help me out on this why it is happening? Before using redux-persist it was fine the reason i am using persist Data lost on Reload But know using Persist when i try to click on some function it reload redirect to login and again redirect to home Weired